# Questions are no longer being accepted

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Right now my Ask Different is no longer accepted questions from my account. Is there a way to override this or am I screwed?

Comment: Kudos to you for asking for help. I’ve added a constructive comment on your most down voted questions - those are the ones where multiple people in the community are saying your post wasn’t useful, or suggesting some research you could do. Feel free to post a new question for one or two of your questions if you can’t figure out how to undelete or edit them if you think there’s any we can help you with.

Comment: I do understand that negative feedback can be hard to accept as helpful sometimes, so don’t worry if you want to do this post in a week or so - there’s no time limit to this and slow is the best way to go with a one post a week throttle in place for the near future.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you’re blocked and no you’re not screwed other than needing to figure out some posts, answer some content and fix some deletions.

Let’s go over all your deleted and closed questions and fix them up. the one that triggered your pause here was one that was pretty clearly off topic and you may have asked it here as you are in a rate limit or block on stack overflow as well.

- [Decompiling the Mac kernel](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335540/decompiling-the-mac-kernel)

That should be migrated, so please let us know (ping here or ask a new meta question) once you’ve sorted out your block status on Stack Overflow so we can migrate it there. Basically, deleting too many questions or having too many closed in a row (on average) is what slows you down either to one question a week or perhaps a hard block.

Once your existing questions are fixed - the system throttle will be lifted and you will be able to ask new questions. This is an automatic block based on patterns of acceptance on your account activity.

- [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/222623)

In a nutshell - a deleted question is the most harmful to have. Don’t delete questions, let them be closed if you can. Fix them and get them reopened as then you can get votes to the positive so the community shows that you’re asking useful (to them at least) questions.

Comment: Ok so should I start with migrating that question to stack overflow? So migrating and deleting then asking in a different group is not the same thing?

Comment: Could we do a quick DM to clarify some things? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Cody Migration is where questions are moved to another Stack Exchange site — you shouldn't delete and re-ask a question somewhere else since that creates two questions and loses the history of the question. There's no DMing on Stack Exchange, but feel free to ask any questions about Ask Different you have in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat)!

Comment: There is quite some important news bit in here. Searched on some metas and didn't find: "where is the exact outline for deleted content still counts for bans". Self-deletion of disapproved content sounds like the 'logical' solution, auto-deletion is not even under the control of a user… Is there more in store in terms of negative effects from deleted content?